# Installation of python's numpy keeps failing

Tags: software-installation, python, numpy

I'm trying to install numpy but the installation keeps failing for some reason.
Actually, what I need is python's [nolearn](https://pythonhosted.org/nolearn/), but numpy (and scipy) are dependencies.

So I ran:

```
sudo pip install numpy
```

But this fails with the installation log:

```
Downloading/unpacking numpy
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/setup.py) egg_info for package numpy
    Running from numpy source directory.

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Running setup.py install for numpy
    /bin/sh: 1: svnversion: not found
    non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
    non-existing path in 'numpy/f2py': 'docs'
    non-existing path in 'numpy/f2py': 'f2py.1'
    F2PY Version 2
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
      FOUND:
        libraries = ['openblas']
        language = f77
        library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']

      FOUND:
        libraries = ['openblas']
        language = f77
        library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']

    /bin/sh: 1: svnversion: not found
    non-existing path in 'numpy/lib': 'benchmarks'
    lapack_opt_info:
    openblas_lapack_info:
    C compiler: cc

    compile options: '-c'
    cc: /tmp/tmpazdxtcf1/source.c
    cc /tmp/tmpazdxtcf1/tmp/tmpazdxtcf1/source.o -lopenblas -o /tmp/tmpazdxtcf1/a.out
      FOUND:
        libraries = ['openblas']
        language = f77
        library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']

      FOUND:
        libraries = ['openblas']
        language = f77
        library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']

    unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
    unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    building library "npymath" sources
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Found executable /usr/bin/gfortran
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    customize Gnu95FCompiler using config
    C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c'
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread _configtest.o -o _configtest
    success!
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest
    C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c'
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c
    _configtest.c:1:5: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘exp’
     int exp (void);
         ^
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread _configtest.o -o _configtest
    _configtest.o: In function `main':
    /tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/_configtest.c:6: undefined reference to `exp'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    _configtest.o: In function `main':
    /tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/_configtest.c:6: undefined reference to `exp'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    failure.
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
    C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c'
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c
    _configtest.c:1:5: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘exp’
     int exp (void);
         ^
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread _configtest.o -lm -o _configtest
    success!
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npymath/ieee754.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_complex.c
    building library "npysort" sources
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npysort/quicksort.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npysort/mergesort.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npysort/heapsort.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/private/npy_partition.h
      adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/private' to include_dirs.
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/private/npy_binsearch.h
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npysort/binsearch.c
    None - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/private/npy_partition.h', 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/private/npy_binsearch.h']
    building extension "numpy.core._dummy" sources
    Generating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/include/numpy/config.h
    C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c'
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c
    _configtest.c:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include <Python.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    _configtest.c:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include <Python.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    failure.
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
    Running from numpy source directory.
    /usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/setup.py", line 251, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/setup.py", line 243, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
        return old_setup(**new_attr)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/install.py", line 62, in run
        r = self.setuptools_run()
      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/install.py", line 36, in setuptools_run
        return distutils_install.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/install.py", line 583, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build.py", line 39, in run
        old_build.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/build.py", line 126, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 153, in run
        self.build_sources()
      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 170, in build_sources
        self.build_extension_sources(ext)
      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 329, in build_extension_sources
        sources = self.generate_sources(sources, ext)
      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 386, in generate_sources
        source = func(extension, build_dir)
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 432, in generate_config_h
        moredefs, ignored = cocache.check_types(config_cmd, ext, build_dir)
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 42, in check_types
        out = check_types(*a, **kw)
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 293, in check_types
        "Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to "\
    SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.4 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-lsbot4u_-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    /bin/sh: 1: svnversion: not found

non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'

non-existing path in 'numpy/f2py': 'docs'

non-existing path in 'numpy/f2py': 'f2py.1'

F2PY Version 2

blas_opt_info:

blas_mkl_info:

  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']

  NOT AVAILABLE



openblas_info:

  FOUND:

    libraries = ['openblas']

    language = f77

    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']



  FOUND:

    libraries = ['openblas']

    language = f77

    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']



/bin/sh: 1: svnversion: not found

non-existing path in 'numpy/lib': 'benchmarks'

lapack_opt_info:

openblas_lapack_info:

C compiler: cc



creating /tmp/tmpazdxtcf1/tmp

creating /tmp/tmpazdxtcf1/tmp/tmpazdxtcf1

compile options: '-c'

cc: /tmp/tmpazdxtcf1/source.c

cc /tmp/tmpazdxtcf1/tmp/tmpazdxtcf1/source.o -lopenblas -o /tmp/tmpazdxtcf1/a.out

  FOUND:

    libraries = ['openblas']

    language = f77

    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']



  FOUND:

    libraries = ['openblas']

    language = f77

    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']



running install

running build

running config_cc

unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options

running config_fc

unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options

running build_src

build_src

building py_modules sources

creating build

creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4

creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy

creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/distutils

building library "npymath" sources

customize Gnu95FCompiler

Found executable /usr/bin/gfortran

customize Gnu95FCompiler

customize Gnu95FCompiler using config

C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC



compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c'

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread _configtest.o -o _configtest

success!

removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest

C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC



compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c'

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c

_configtest.c:1:5: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘exp’

 int exp (void);

     ^

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread _configtest.o -o _configtest

_configtest.o: In function `main':

/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/_configtest.c:6: undefined reference to `exp'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

_configtest.o: In function `main':

/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/_configtest.c:6: undefined reference to `exp'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

failure.

removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o

C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC



compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c'

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c

_configtest.c:1:5: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘exp’

 int exp (void);

     ^

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread _configtest.o -lm -o _configtest

success!

removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest

creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core

creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src

creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npymath

conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math.c

conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npymath/ieee754.c

conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_complex.c

building library "npysort" sources

creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npysort

conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npysort/quicksort.c

conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npysort/mergesort.c

conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npysort/heapsort.c

creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/private

conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/private/npy_partition.h

  adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/private' to include_dirs.

conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c

conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/private/npy_binsearch.h

conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npysort/binsearch.c

None - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/private/npy_partition.h', 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/private/npy_binsearch.h']

building extension "numpy.core._dummy" sources

Generating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/include/numpy/config.h

C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC



compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c'

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c

_configtest.c:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include <Python.h>

                    ^

compilation terminated.

_configtest.c:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include <Python.h>

                    ^

compilation terminated.

failure.

removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o

Running from numpy source directory.

/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'

  warnings.warn(msg)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/setup.py", line 251, in <module>

    setup_package()

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/setup.py", line 243, in setup_package

    setup(**metadata)

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup

    return old_setup(**new_attr)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/install.py", line 62, in run

    r = self.setuptools_run()

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/install.py", line 36, in setuptools_run

    return distutils_install.run(self)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/install.py", line 583, in run

    self.run_command('build')

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build.py", line 39, in run

    old_build.run(self)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/build.py", line 126, in run

    self.run_command(cmd_name)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 153, in run

    self.build_sources()

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 170, in build_sources

    self.build_extension_sources(ext)

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 329, in build_extension_sources

    sources = self.generate_sources(sources, ext)

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 386, in generate_sources

    source = func(extension, build_dir)

  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 432, in generate_config_h

    moredefs, ignored = cocache.check_types(config_cmd, ext, build_dir)

  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 42, in check_types

    out = check_types(*a, **kw)

  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 293, in check_types

    "Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to "\

SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python3.4 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-lsbot4u_-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/numpy
Storing debug log for failure in /home/mikel/.pip/pip.log
```

It says there `Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel` but I don't. When I try to install python-dev it says:

```
python-dev is already the newest version.
```

My guess is that the source of the problem is the warning:

```
_configtest.c:1:5: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘exp’
 int exp (void);
```

But I have no clue on how to tackle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the old version can be installed with pip. You may wish to install the latest version with git.

The short version is:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.4-dev
git clone git@github.com:dnouri/nolearn.git
cd nolearn
pip install -r requirements.txt
python setup.py develop
```

This should install including all requirements.

You also need the python 3.4 development package.

Sources:

https://github.com/dnouri/nolearn

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892810/python-3-4-and-2-7-cannot-install-numpy-package-for-python-3-4

Comment: I get the exact same error with exactly the same warning I mentioned above...

Comment: which exact same error? No change in output whatsoever?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/dh_numpy.1.html  I'm not positive but you may require strict  versioned depends  on  python-numpy,  and using this helper script is the touted as the easiest   and most consistent way to get them. Available for 12.04 through 15.04

Comment: Here are the last result: 
`SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.

non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'

non-existing path in 'numpy/f2py': 'docs'

non-existing path in 'numpy/f2py': 'f2py.1'

non-existing path in 'numpy/lib': 'benchmarks'

_configtest.o: In function `main':

/tmp/easy_install-1t3edv02/numpy-1.9.2/_configtest.c:6: undefined reference to `exp'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

_configtest.c:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include <Python.h>`